Turing Machine quintuples to 2-tag system transformation
I made a Turing machine emulator that takes as input the transition table for a machine and its input, and executes it.
I would now like to give it the description of a universal Turing machine, and the encoded description of one of my previous ones.
So I picked Minsky's U(4,7) and made a description for it, but I struggle to understand how to turn the list of quintuples describing the other TM into a 2-tag system that U(4,7) takes as input.
I've found a few papers describing the process, but I never formally studied math and get a bit lost by the demonstration (I looked at Three Small Universal Turing Machines - C.Baiocchi and Minsky's Small Univeral Turing Machine - Robinson)
I believe I understand the bases of how a 2-tag system works, but have difficulty understanding how to go from one to the other.
Could someone explain it in a bit more layman’s terms?
